# MediaPlaybackControls windows phone 8

Tags: video, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app for video playback. Once a video starts, I want the user to be able to switch between videos without exiting the `MediaPlayerLauncher`. So I was thinking of adding a fourth control on top of the 3 (rewind, pause, fast forward) that windows phone displays for the videos. I looked into `MediaPlaybackControls` and saw that it has a control for Skip also. So I added the following line(s) in my code to show the Skip control.

```
MediaPlayerLauncher launcher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
launcher.Media = entry.Uri;
launcher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Rewind | MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | 
                     MediaPlaybackControls.FastForward | MediaPlaybackControls.Skip;
launcher.Show();
```

entry.Uri is the URI for the video that I am trying to play. I would expect all 4 controls to show up when playing the video, but only the original 3 show up. Also I noticed that there is no way to specify multiple video files to the `MediaPlayerLauncher` object because the Media field accepts only one URI.

So can someone please help me with how I can show the Skip control along with Rewind, Pause and, Fast Forward and also how I can switch videos once Skip is pressed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayerLauncher isn't really meant for that usecase. And even at this usecase it does an "OK job". For example MediaPlayerLauncher doesn't support titles, subtitles, overlays, etc.

If you're trying to playback a list of items or want a tailored UI/UX for your media playback experience it's best to use [SmfPlayer](http://smf.codeplex.com/) which in turn uses the built-in  MediaElement or SmoothStreamingMediaElement.

For example, here's [how to](http://smf.codeplex.com/documentation) create a playlist of several items with SmfPlayer for WP7:

```
<Core:SMFPlayer>
    <Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
        <Media:PlaylistItem MediaSource="http://smf.vertigo.com/videos/wildlife.wmv"/>
        <Media:PlaylistItem MediaSource="http://smf.vertigo.com/videos/wildlife.wmv"/>
        <Media:PlaylistItem DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" MediaSource="http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/smoothcontent/bbbwp7/big buck bunny.ism/manifest"/>
    </Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
</Core:SMFPlayer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't. For this kind of scenario you should use `MediaElement` inside your app.

However then you will need to build the controls yourself in your app.